# selecting elements of c++ vector by passing boolean values of whether to pick an index

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing

In python, we can select a subset of an array by passing boolean values of whether to include the value at an index or not by:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
b=a[np.array([False, True, True,False, True, True])
print(b) # prints array([2, 3, 5, 6])
```

Is there a C++ equivalent for this?

Comment: When dealing in Turing complete languages there is always an equivalent. I'm not aware of anything that does this right out of the box, but [`std::copy_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) should get you started.

Comment: An exact equivalent can be made. However, it will be somewhat awkward and potentially inefficient. In C++ you are better off folding more stuff into a single loop (such as creating the booleans, then copying the filtered values), rather than creating a temporary boolean vector, then iterating over that again. Therefore it is better to look at a specific task. Where does this boolean array come from? Is it reused? Is it derived from the ```a``` array via some form of comparison?

Comment: *In python, we can* - it is not very correct statement. It should be *In python math library, we can*. So the question about looking for a library is of-topic.

Comment: There is indeed a std class with such a feature: std::valarray. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/operator_at

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a C++ equivalent: [`std::copy_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int func1() {
    std::vector<int> from_vector = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    std::vector<int> to_vector;

    std::copy_if(from_vector.begin(), from_vector.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "),
        [](int x) { return x % 3 != 1; });  // prints 2, 3, 5, 6

    std::copy_if(from_vector.begin(), from_vector.end(),
        std::back_inserter(to_vector),
        [](int x) { return x % 3 != 1; });
    // to_vector contains {2, 3, 5, 6}
}

//
// A bit closer equivalent to the code in the question.
// @user4581301: A great example of how not to translate Python to C++.
//

#include <deque>

int func2() {
    std::vector<int> from_vector = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    std::deque<bool> filter = {false, true, true, false, true, true};
    std::vector<int> to_vector;

    std::copy_if(from_vector.begin(), from_vector.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "),
        [&filter](int x) {
            if (filter.empty()) return false;
            const bool rv = filter.front();
            filter.pop_front();
            return rv;
        });  // prints 2, 3, 5, 6

    std::copy_if(from_vector.begin(), from_vector.end(),
        std::back_inserter(to_vector),
        [&filter](int x) {
            if (filter.empty()) return false;
            const bool rv = filter.front();
            filter.pop_front();
            return rv;
        });
    // to_vector contains {2, 3, 5, 6}
}
```

Comment: Worth throwing a bone at the asker and showing how to do this with the filtering array instead of just the math way.

Comment: Should not be it of-topic? As I commented above, the question is more about looking for a library.

Comment: I think it can be written in such a way that it'll show the asker how to do it without actually making it useful without a lot more work. Also it would be pretty gross. A great example of how not to translate Python to C++.

Comment: `deque` is sneaky. When you initially answered I was playing with [a state-full functor.](https://godbolt.org/z/6EWT85bGK).

Comment: @user4581301 A functor would make a less great *example of how not to translate Python to C++*.